# How to send every command to Emacs Term?

Tags: emacs, terminal, elisp

Is it possible to configure emacs term to send everything (maybe exception M-x) as raw commands. This will allow for instance run emacs -nw inside terminal and every command will work for emacs inside terminal now the one outside.

I want something like this because I sometimes run nano from terminal or screen, I also use ssh and this will alow me to run emacs on the server. Right now when I run nano I need to call C-c x that send C-x.

Comment: Are you asking about `term-mode`?

Comment: @jpkotta Yes term-mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd first suggest using [`tramp`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) to edit remote files.  I prefer it to opening an editor on the remote machine.  If you try to run emacs inside a `term-mode` buffer, you're going to be fighting it all the time.

If you must run emacs inside a `term-mode` buffer, you can use `term-send-raw` and `term-send-raw-string`.  For example:

```
(defun term-send-backward-word ()
  "Move backward word in term mode."
  (interactive)
  (term-send-raw-string "\eb"))
```

`<Escape> b` is what the terminal (which is `eterm-color`) expects when you press `C-<left>`.  This is not necessarily the same as binding `C-<left>` to `term-send-raw`.  The best thing to do is probably to try binding whatever key to `term-send-raw`, and if that doesn't work, make a function with `term-send-raw-string` and bind that.  You can figure out what the string should be if you have a shell in the `term-mode` buffer, send a quote, and then type the key.  You can send a quote with

```
(defun term-send-quote ()
  "Quote the next character in term-mode.
Similar to how `quoted-insert' works in a regular buffer."
  (interactive)
  (term-send-raw-string "\C-v"))
```

It's just like typing `C-v` in a normal terminal.

Finally, I'll mention [`multi-term`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm).  It's available in melpa.  It provides the functions I listed above, and has better defaults than `term-mode` IMO.  But it's probably further from what you want, because it tries to integrate `term-mode` with the rest of emacs instead of just passing things through.